# MongoDb backup script not producing backup files in backup folder

Tags: mongodb, powershell

I have written the following powershell script to backup all my databases in mongodb:

```
# Define the backup directory
$backupDirectory = "C:\MongoDBBackups"

# Check if the backup directory exists
if (!(Test-Path -Path $backupDirectory)) {
    # If it doesn't, create the directory
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $backupDirectory | Out-Null
}

# Define the log file path
$logFile = "C:\MongoDBBackups\log.log"

# Delete the existing backup directory
Remove-Item -Path $backupDirectory -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Create the backup directory
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $backupDirectory

$dbs = mongo --quiet --host 127.0.0.1:27017 --eval "db.getMongo().getDBNames()"

foreach ($db in $dbs) {
    try {
        #Remove illegal characters from the file name
        $fileName = $db
        $fileName = $fileName -replace '[/\\:*?"<>|]',''
        # Perform the backup for each database
        mongodump --db $db --out $backupDirectory\$fileName
        Write-Output "Exported $db database." | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
    } catch {
            $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            Write-Output "Error: $errorMessage" | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
    }
}

# Print a message to confirm the backup is complete
Write-Output "Backup of all databases complete." | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
```

The issue I am running into is that my backup folder seems to only produce my log file and nothing else. My log file shows that my databases hvae been backed up but I am getting no output. I am not sure where the issue lies. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `Write-Output "mongodump --db $db --out $backupDirectory\$fileName"` Then try to run the generated commands manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my issue! My script was giving strings of the databases instead of the actual database names within the input when using mongodump I solved it by adding the following line before my foreach

```
$dbsString = $dbsString -join ""
$dbs = ConvertFrom-Json $dbsString
```